# Formal "total cost of services rendered" in german

Tags: formality

When rendering the services to the clients, one usually deals with legal documents.

In the post-soviet countries there is a document called *protocol of delivery-acceptance of services rendered* in which it is stated

> Total cost of services rendered *(or provided)* is USD 1,00.

The only translation that comes to my mind is

> Gesamtkosten der erbrachten Leistungen macht USD 1,00 aus.

What is the more formal way to express the same? Thanks.

Comment: "erbrachte Leistungen" is fine. If I would replace anything in that sentence, it'd be "ausmachen". I'd go with "ergeben", "betragen", "sich belaufen auf".

Comment: Die Gesamtkosten der erbrachten Leistungen summieren sich auf 1 USD / betragen 1 USD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

> Die Gesamtkosten der erbrachten Leistungen betragen USD 1,00.